# Matching records based on a scoring algorithm - supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am trying to find whether/how supervised learning technique can be applied to the following situation.

**Problem details:**

We have a database of our client's customers (few hundred thousand) in our system. Our clients are small businesses. All of the customer data was added manually by our clients over the past many years. We are trying to automate the process a bit for our new clients when they setup our service for the first time. We have a vendor who is ready to supply a huge database (let us name it as CUSTOMER_DB) - a super set of all the customers of our existing clients and potential clients - but there is no mapping available between businesses and customers. We want to make our new clients/businesses lives easier by predicting the list of their customers instead of them manually adding one by one, when they setup our service.

Now, for a given client (say A), there are set of properties (less than 10) that we can use to map records in CUSTOMER_DB to A. E.g., location, membership, etc.. We would like to surface the best matches based on a scoring algorithm, so that our clients could just choose from the best matches we surface. And add the rest through a search tool. As there is enough training data (business to customer mapping of our existing clients), I guess it may be possible to come up with a scoring algorithm to find out best matches.

Assuming a scoring algorithm is a reasonable solution, the problem is to identify the scores for each of the match-able property of a customer. For example location match may have score 10 (randomly chosen) and membership match may have a score of 8 (again randomly chosen), etc... Now, I need to set these scores for every property that will be matched against, and also set a minimum total score for a customer record to decide whether to surface the record to the client.

**Questions**

1. Is Supervised Learning apt for this problem? Or an overkill? Or
   cannot be applied?
2. If yes, is there an open source solution to this
   type of problems?
3. If no, could you give point me towards a better
   alternative?
4. If there is no open source solution (which I doubt), is
   this something that a new ML developer like me could solve in a
   couple of weeks? Or is that too optimistic?

Thank you for your time. I am not sure whether I explained the problem well enough. Please ask if I need to elaborate more or any clarifying questions.

Comment: sounds like a simple recommender system to me

Comment: @zacdav Thank you! Is there a open source library for this? Or is straight forward enough for a beginner in ML to implement? Any pointers would be helpful. Thank you.